# Database migration from Contao 2.11 to Magento 2.3 or Shopware 6.1

Tags: shell, magento, database-migration, shopware, contao

We have an Contao 2.11 e-shop with highly customised functionalities. Now we decided to move from contao to Magento 2.3/Shopware 6.1 but not yet sure which one will be best.

For any case, we need to migrate the database. We already checked if there any plugin/extension that supports this migration but so far no luck.

Shopware has data migration plugin that helps to make it works but it does not support Contao.And We also could not find any extension that helps to migrate the data from Contao to magento 2.3 too.

So if there is no extension/plugin then definitely we have to write a custom script to do it.

Any information from you will be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a magento migration-tool for shopware:
I think the easiest way is to adapt this tool and change it to your needs. It simply reads the database and converts the information to shopware entities. So the whole "write process" should already be done within this tool and you only need to adjust the reading and conversion process.